# Error in read.table ; more column than column names

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to develop a shiny APP, and when I trying to import the file, then I am getting an error,

> more column than column names

The code I am using with Ui and server is quite long, since I am importing the data by user, from R environment . this is a piece of code, I suspect to have error with

```
if(input$data_source=="import"& !is.null(prev_table$file_path)){
        df_view <- NULL
        prev_table$class <- NULL
        prev_table$df_name <- substr(prev_table$file_name,1,regexpr(".", prev_table$file_name, fixed=T)-1)
        df_view <- read.csv(prev_table$file_path, stringsAsFactors =FALSE)
        prev_table$class <- class(df_view)
      }else{
        df_view <- NULL
      }
      return(df_view)
  })

 output$view_table <- DT::renderDataTable(
   df_tb1_view()[1:10,],
   server=FALSE,
   rownames=FALSE,
   options=list(pageLength=10,
                lengthMenu=NULL)
 )
```

Could anyone tell me , What could be the possibility for this error.

Comment: My guess is your data contains entries that contain the delimiter. For instance, if your data is *comma*-separated and an entry has a *comma*, when read, that row will look like it has more entries than other rows and the header (column names)

Comment: Have you checked if your csv files have extra rows before the actual data?